# How to override the massactions.js in magento 2.4.X?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I want to override only this js file

> vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/massactions.js

I tried the same location and added file but didn't worked.
Please can anyone tell me, How can I override only this js file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the mixins feature, all you need is to create a requireJS module with an extended method like this:

default_mixin.js:

```
define(function () {
'use strict';

var mixin = {

    methodToExtend: function () {
        //...
    }
};

return function (target) { // target == Result that Magento_Ui/.../default returns.
    return target.extend(mixin); // new result that all other modules receive 
};
```

});

requirejs-config.js:

```
config: {
mixins: {
    'My_Module/js/payment/default': {  // Target module
        'My_Module/js/payment/default_mixin': true  // Extender module
    }
}
```

}

reference link : [Extend massactions.js](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74880/extend-massactions-js)

Comment: Thanks, It's working.